# VBA Function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie in Excel VBA. I am trying to do a very simple function which will works like IF a specific cell (for example D) contains some categorized string then it will return a specific value in another cell.

For an example if any cell of column D contains 'Books', 'Food', 'Fruits' string anywhere of its cell then it will return 01, 02, 03 respectively in Column E. For sure it will very easy task and probably this kind of question asked earlier but as I am newbie please let me know in a brief or any link to get the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We understand that you are new to vba programming but can you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I am now trying with the following answer 1 codes but its returning error. 'Else without If'

Comment: I can give you the answer. It is very obvious in that post but here is a hint... http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vbabasic3.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix to an answer below

```
For Counter = 1 To 2000
    Set curCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 4)
    '  'Books', 'Food', 'Fruits
    If curCell.Value = "Books" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 5) = 1
    ElseIf curCell.Value = "Food" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 5) = 2
    ElseIf curCell.Value = "Fruits" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 5) = 3
    End If
Next Counter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Counter = 1 To 2000
    Set curCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 4)
    '  'Books', 'Food', 'Fruits
    If curCell.Value = "Books" Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 5) = 01
    elseIf curCell.Value = "Food" Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 5) = 02 
    elseIf curCell.Value = "Fruits" Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 5) = 03
    end if
Next Counter
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a macro.
You can use `Vlookup` on the second column to search for the value of the first column on a table.